# Is there a way to retrieve the version (git commit hash) of a provided tag on the provider side

Tags: rest, command-line-interface, pact, pact-broker

I have tagged “deployed-prod” on my provider for a specific old commit on Pact Broker and now I want to retrieve that commit hash so that I can build the provider from that commit hash to perform contract verification. Is there an API or CLI I can use to retrieve that?

I have looked up all the documentation but only found ways to the retrieve pact by the provided consumer version or tag(s).